# CSS - linter vs. beautifier inconsistency

Tags: css, gruntjs, csslint, js-beautify

I am using grunt-jsbeautifier to pretty-print a .css file, and grunt-contrib-csslint to check the .css file for problems.  Unfortunately the beautifier seems to produce CSS which violates a linter rule.

If I have this CSS:

```
.half_circle_style a:nth-child(2) {}
```

...then grunt-contrib-csslint reports "Done, without errors".

If I run the CSS through grunt-jsbeautifier, a space gets added before nth-child:

```
.half_circle_style a: nth-child(2) {}
```

... which causes grunt-contrib-csslint to report:

```
[L1:C23]
>> Expected LBRACE at line 1, col 23. This rule looks for recoverable syntax errors. (errors)
[L1:C23]
>> Unexpected token 'nth-child(' at line 1, col 23. This rule looks for recoverable syntax errors. (errors)
[L1:C33]
>> Unexpected token '2' at line 1, col 33. This rule looks for recoverable syntax errors. (errors)
[L1:C34]
>> Unexpected token ')' at line 1, col 34. This rule looks for recoverable syntax errors. (errors)
[L1:C36]
>> Unexpected token '{' at line 1, col 36. This rule looks for recoverable syntax errors. (errors)
[L1:C37]
>> Unexpected token '}' at line 1, col 37. This rule looks for recoverable syntax errors. (errors)
```

I'm not a CSS expert, so I'm looking for an expert opinion, please - is grunt-jsbeautifier pretty printing badly, or is grunt-contrib-csslint being overly-strict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance I don't believe grunt-contrib-csslint is being overly strict.

```
.half_circle_style a:nth-child(2) {}
```

is valid CSS syntax, whereas

```
.half_circle_style a: nth-child(2) {}
```

(with a space before `nth-child`) is not valid CSS syntax.

Could the issue be because you are running your CSS through a JavaScript beautifying engine as opposed to a CSS one? Maybe you could try running your code through http://cssbeautify.com/

Comment: Thanks - I'll raise a support case with jsbeautifier.